# For Loop and Nested If Statement Comparison, simplification in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to see if there is a better way to simplify this nested if statement that I am comparing. Since each elif has it's own unique lists in them I would assume it does have to be specifically stated.

My goal is to see where a starting XY position would be that is randomly picked and whichever one is randomly selected have a set of restraining corresponding XY positions that would determine the next XY movement.

Here is what I have so far:

```
global_top_coords = [[5,190],
                     [97,190],
                     [188,190],
                     [279,190],
                     [370,190],
                     [462,190],
                     [553,190],
                     [644,190],
                     [750,190]]

perimeter_list= global_top_coords

random_xy_start = random.choice(perimeter_list)
for i in (perimeter_list):
    if random_xy_start == perimeter_list[0]:
        x_list = (75, 100, 125, 150)
        y_list = (75, 100, 125)
        x_rel = random.choice(x_list)
        y_rel = random.choice(y_list)
        xy_rel = (x_rel, y_rel)
        break
    elif random_xy_start == perimeter_list[1]:
        x_list = (75, 100, 125, 150)
        y_list = (75, 100, 125)
        x_rel = random.choice(x_list)
        y_rel = random.choice(y_list)
        xy_rel = (x_rel, y_rel)
        break
    elif random_xy_start == perimeter_list[2]:
        x_list = (-150, -125, -100, -75, 75, 100, 125, 150)
        y_list = (75, 100, 125)
        x_rel = random.choice(x_list)
        y_rel = random.choice(y_list)
        xy_rel = (x_rel, y_rel)
        break
    elif random_xy_start == perimeter_list[3:7]:
        x_list = (-150, -125, -100, -75, 75, 100, 125, 150)
        y_list = (75, 100, 125)
        x_rel = random.choice(x_list)
        y_rel = random.choice(y_list)
        xy_rel = (x_rel, y_rel)
        break
    elif random_xy_start == perimeter_list[7]:
        x_list = (-150, -125, -100, -75, 75)
        y_list = (75, 100, 125)
        x_rel = random.choice(x_list)
        y_rel = random.choice(y_list)
        xy_rel = (x_rel, y_rel)
        break
    elif random_xy_start == perimeter_list[8]:
        x_list = (-150, -125, -100, -75)
        y_list = (75, 100, 125)
        x_rel = random.choice(x_list)
        y_rel = random.choice(y_list)
        xy_rel = (x_rel, y_rel)
        break
xy_rel
```

I will be adding more to the initial perimeter list down the line but wanted to start with just the top perimeter coordinates to see how it would play out. So you could imagine I will be adding starting coordinates for the left, right, and bottom perimeter as well to the perimeter_list. This will then require a completely different set of if statement comparisons which is why I would like to see if there is a simpler way to loop through this.

Comment: The for loop is not used. Any reason to have it?

Comment: If the code works and you are only looking for ways to simplify it, this question may be a better fit for [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: How could `random_xy_start == perimeter_list[3:7]` considering random_xy_start is a 1D list and perimeter_list[3:7] is 2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of common code that you can do after the `if` statement instead of in each case. These three lines could be moved so they aren't repeated:

```
x_rel = random.choice(x_list)
y_rel = random.choice(y_list)
xy_rel = (x_rel, y_rel)
```

You can also combine some of the conditions where blocks of code are exactly the same. For example, the first two could be combined by

```
if random_xy_start == perimeter_list[0] or random_xy_start == perimeter_list[1]:
```

Also, you're breaking out of the loop after one iteration in every case of the `if` statement. Do you really need the loop at all?

Finally, `elif random_xy_start == perimeter_list[3:7]` can never be `True`, since `random_xy_start` is a list and `perimeter_list[3:7]` is a list of lists. You might want to change that to `elif random_xy_start in perimeter_list[3:7]` instead. (Other combined conditions could be changed to use `in` as well.)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider having a "master" list of x_list since it seems like y_list never changes.
Also, you can find the index of an element in a list using `.index()` so you don't really need to use `if/else` blocks.

```
random_xy_start = random.choice(global_top_coords)
x_lists = [(75, 100, 125, 150),
           (75, 100, 125, 150),
           (-150, -125, -100, -75, 75, 100, 125, 150),
           (-150, -125, -100, -75, 75, 100, 125, 150),
           (-150, -125, -100, -75, 75, 100, 125, 150),
           (-150, -125, -100, -75, 75, 100, 125, 150),
           (-150, -125, -100, -75, 75, 100, 125, 150),
           (-150, -125, -100, -75, 75, 100, 125, 150),
           (-150, -125, -100, -75)]

xy_rel = (random.choice(x_lists[global_top_coords.index(random_xy_start)]),
          random.choice((75, 100, 125)))
```